# vb.net xml atom feed get attributes

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'd like to get some lines out of an atom feed/xml file and put into an database.  I know how to enter strings into a database, but I'm struggling to understand how to work with xml files as this is my first time.
Lets say the xml file is "C:\feed.xml" and looks like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title>This is the Title</title>
  <link href="https://www.website.com"></link>
  <entry>
    <title>Title 1</title>
    <link href="http://www.website.com/Title/page1"></link>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <title>Title 2</title>
    <link href="http://www.website.com/Title/page2"></link>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

pseudo code...

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("C:\feed.xml")

For i = 0 to entry.count - 1
  Dim String1 as String = title(i).InnerText
  Dim String2 as String = link href(i).InnerText
  database.insert(String1, String2)
Next i
```

Don't worry about the database.insert part, I know how to do that, I just need help getting String1 and String2.  Specifically String2 as I need it to just be String2 = "http//www.website.com/Title/page1" (note : missing on purpose)

Any help is most appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: See [SyndicationFeed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try following xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim feed As XElement = doc.Root
        Dim ns As XNamespace = feed.GetDefaultNamespace()

        Dim results = doc.Elements(ns + "feed").Select(Function(x) New With { _
                                                      .title = CType(x.Element(ns + "title"), String), _
                                                      .link = CType(x.Element(ns + "link").Attribute("href"), String), _
                                                      .entry = x.Elements(ns + "entry").Select(Function(y) New With {
                                                                                               .title = CType(y.Element(ns + "title"), String), _
                                                                                               .link = CType(y.Element(ns + "link").Attribute("href"), String) _
                                                                                               }).ToList()
                                                  }).FirstOrDefault()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SyndicationFeed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Add reference to System.ServiceModel.dll assembly.

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Syndication
Imports System.Xml


Using xmlReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("C:\feed.xml")
    Dim feed As SyndicationFeed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader)

    Console.WriteLine(feed.Title.Text)

    For Each link In feed.Links
        Console.WriteLine(link.Uri)
    Next

    For Each entry In feed.Items
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text)
        For Each link In entry.Links
            Console.WriteLine(link.Uri)
        Next
    Next
End Using
```